# How to make the "done" button on numeric keyboard do some action?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` which InputType is Numeric, and a `TextView`. What I want to realize is, when the user inserts some `integer value` in the `EditText`, make the "Done" button on the Numeric keyboard store the inserted value and display it in the `TextView`. How can I realize that? Thanks!!!

Comment: you can making it in edittext onchange action instead of keyboard action

Answer (score 6):

First make sure that you have the done ime option set on your EditText

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Then in the code you add a listener to your `EditText`

```
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // do something, e.g. set your TextView here via .setText()
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: When I set int credits = Integer.parseInt(creditsS); TextView.setText("" + credits); the app crashes... I don't understand...

Comment: Numerous possible reasons, what Exception are you receiving in the log? If you need more help you should post your code & preferably crash logs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to Android. Don't worry just use in `xml`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_ip"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Numeric" />
```

In Activity

```
EditText iput= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_ip);
TextView  oput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_op); 
Button done = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tv_op);
```

//and onbuttonclick

```
done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

String result = iput.getText().toString().trim();


//result have the value in edittext in string
oput.setText(result);



        });
```

Any more doubt ??